# Why does this one-liner clobber files?

Tags: bash, find, tr

I have written this to help me batch-encode some videos:

```
find -name '*.mkv' -exec HandBrakeCLI -Z "Android Tablet" \
  -c "1-3" -m -O --x264-tune film -E copy --decomb -s 1 -i {} \
  -o `echo {} | tr mkv m4v` \;
```

However, it fails catastrophically -- it takes each 700-900MB file and replaces it with a 36KB file.

Notably, HandBrake is able to read and print the properties of the video file; it is only when it moves on to encode it that it fails because the file is invalid. So it appears that the overwriting occurs when it gets to...

```
-o `echo {} | tr mkv m4v`
```

...but I am not sure why it should. I am simply trying to change the output filename from whatever.mkv to whatever.m4v

The filenames do not have spaces. They are of the form `12-the-revenge.mkv`, for instance.

Comment: The command `tr mkv m4v` translates every "k" in the input to "4" leaving other characters unchanged; thus "kicking.mkv" would become "4ic4ing.m4v" which is probably not what you intend.

Comment: What do you get when you run the command on one file (without the `find`) using the same set of options? I'm guessing that you get a 36KB file, and if you add `--verbose` it might give you some information about why it is failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The backticked expression: `echo {} | tr mkv m4v` (which is *not* what you want, for a variety of reasons; see below) is expanded once, when the find command is parsed. If you're using `bash`, it will normally be expanded to `{}`:

```
$ echo {} | tr mkv m4v
{}
```

And, indeed, that happens on every shell installed on my machine except fish, which outputs an empty line. Assuming you're not using `fish`, then the arguments `find` is actually seeing will be:

```
find -name '*.mkv' -exec HandBrakeCLI -Z "Android Tablet" \
-c "1-3" -m -O --x264-tune film -E copy --decomb -s 1 -i {} \
-o {} \;
```

In short, `HandBrakeCLI` is being given the same file for both input and output, and I think that's what you're seeing, although your description of the symptoms is not very precise.

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to get find to do the extension replacement you want it to do within an `-exec` action. You could do it by passing the command to `bash -c`, but that will involve extra, confusing quoting on the command line. A cleaner and more readable solution is to create a shell script file which can iterate through it's arguments:

File: `mkvtom4v.sh` (Make sure you `chmod a+x mkvtom4v.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "$@"; do
  HandBrakeCLI -Z "Android Tablet" -c "1-3" -m -O \
               --x264-tune film -E copy --decomb -s 1 \
               -i "$file" -o "${file/%.mkv/.m4v}"
done
```

And then invoke it with find:

```
find /path/to/directory -name '*.mkv' -exec /path/to/mkvtom4v.sh {} +
```

---

Some notes:

1. Don't use backticks (`some command`); they have been deprecated for many years. Use `$(some command)`, which is more readable and allows nesting.
2. `tr` is definitely not what you want. It does character by character translation. For example, `tr aeiou AEIOU` would make all vOwEls UppErcAsE. `tr mkv m4v` will change every `k` to a `4`. See `man tr` (or `info tr`) for more details.
3. `"${file/%.mkv/.m4v}"` is bash's idiosyncratic search-and-replace syntax. In this case, it means: "Take the value of `$file`, and if it ends with `.mkv` (the `%` means "ends with" in this context), then replace it with `.m4v`". There are lots of other bashisms for editing the value of a variable. `man bash` and search for "Parameter Expansion".
4. With GNU find, you can use `{} +` at the end of an `-exec` command (instead of `\;`). It will be replaced by as many found filenames as possible. See `info find` for more details.

Comment: OK, so as I understand it, the problem was that `tr` was run before `find`, so the output file was just `{}` and hence the same as the input? And I had a feeling that I misremembered the operation of `tr`, but it worked when I tested it outside `find` so I stupidly went with it. Anyway, your solution works, thanks!

Comment: @user45084: Yep ("HandBrakeCLI is being given the same file for both input and output"). `find` will replace both instances of `{}` with the filename, in a single-file `-exec`.

Comment: @gilles: the shell script creates one bash process (for up to hundreds of files, probably). A single file `-exec bash -c` creates an extra bash *per file*. But thanks  for the edit, anyway: its clearer than mine was.

Comment: @rici That's purely a matter of using `+` vs `;` at the end of the `-exec` clause. It's unrelated with the shell program being in a `-c` argument or in a script.